# Meaning of messy code in parsed RDF/XML triples?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdflib, ifc

I used the codes below to parse a RDF and get triples in excel.

```
import rdflib
import pandas as pd

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.load('https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/OWL/')

lst_s = []
lst_p = []
lst_o = []

for s, p, o in g:
    lst_s.append(s)
    lst_p.append(p)
    lst_o.append(o)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst_s,lst_p,lst_o)), columns=['s','p','o'])
df.to_excel("ifc owl.xlsx")
```

I found that there are some messy codes like this：
[image]

I looked at the N Triples format and found that the highlighted triple in the excel above is as below:
[image]
It seems that the messy code is the "genid2542?". What is the meaning of such messy codes? Is it because of the parsing errors or it corresponds to some meanings? Thank you!

Comment: what means "messy"? Those identifiers refer to RDF blank nodes which do not have an identity in real would. Nevertheless they are unique per document. If you don't like those, replace them by a URI. But it would change the semantics.

Comment: "messy" means the codes that looks like to be comprised of random numbers/characters such as Naec70314609c4dcbb503e15bcceb93e0, just like the one circled in red in the first attached picture. So is it generated automatically by the computer when parsing? It is a node with no value or such random codes?

Comment: it is an RDF blank node: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-blank-nodes - and yes, this identifier could change each time you parse the RDF document. The only restriction is that it has to be unique document wide when using it.

Comment: keep in mind that every tool that touches a blank node is not only free to but in some cases *must* rewrite  them as a different "messy codes" as such some tools may proactively rewrite them all just in case.  this is to handle combining multiple files with  coincidentally identical "messy codes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just re-posting some points from the comments as an answer that can be accepted:*

Those identifiers refer to RDF blank nodes (https://w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-blank-nodes) which do not have an identity in real world. They are unique per document.

Keep in mind that every tool that touches a blank node is not only free to, but in some cases *must*, rewrite them as a different.